# Most popular mobile platform to develop on?

Tags: mobile, popularity

This question may not directly relate to programming. I have noticed that the technology of today has gone mobile. I want to go mobile with it. What is the most popular mobile OS?(**excluding iPhone OS**. Sorry, I don't have a Mac to develop on) Some choices could be BlackBerry OS, Windows Phone, Symbian OS, Android OS, etc. I want to make and sell applications for a mobile OS.

Comment: IIRC this is a duplicate Q...

Comment: "popular" can unfortunately mean many things. in decreasing order of size, worldwide runtime installation base probably look like j2me, flash lite, symbian c++, iphone, android... that changes widely with geography. now if you're talking about the "new" tech that the press and bloggers like, then yes, android is your answer. part of that would have to do with installation base size trend, meaning how fast the runtime market share changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have Java experience, learn [**Android**](http://developer.android.com/index.html). It's becoming widely popular next to the iPhone. Although, I cannot prove that it is the *most* popular mobile platform to develop on, but it's popularity is increasing.

If you are interested in publishing an applcation for Android you would need to [signup](http://market.android.com/publish/signup) on the Android Market.

It would also be wise to read the [**Android Market Developer Distribution Agreement**](http://www.android.com/us/developer-distribution-agreement.html) so you can learn about processing payments, fees, and any other aspect when publishing paid apps.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to throw in the mix while deciding this is the percentage of handsets having a given platform in your target market. Iphone and Android seems to be the platforms for the future, their adoption is going to increase. But if your target market, say India has a significant number of J2ME supporting handsets, then it would make sense to start on J2ME. This aspect needs to be researched and factored in while making your decision.

Also if you design carefully it possible to support multiple platforms, say, Android and BlackBerry since both are Java based.

Answer (score 0):

Difficult question.
While Blackberry detains the biggest share on mobile market, Android is surely coming out fast. I think Windows Mobile isn't at the level of the others, so my choices are BlackBerry and Android. If I have to choose, for the future, Android.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Anthony, Android is the way to go if you have Java experience. If you have more Microsoft experience, then take a look at Windows Phone 7. It's totally different than all previous Microsoft phone systems and everybody is starting from scratch. It's anybody's guess how successful it's going to be but it does have a big company behind it, and what you learn there will be applicable to many non-mobile scenarios as well whether you choose Silverlight or XNA as your development environment.

Answer (score 0):

A survey by [Admob](http://admob.com) http://metrics.admob.com/2010/03/admob-publisher-survey/

Pretty much explains what you are asking :)

Comment: 108 admob publishers answered the survey. hardly representative of the industry. It was definitely worth posting that here but let's not confuse this with a scientific result.